# Is there an equivalent to OpenGL glVertexAttrib() in D3D11?

Tags: c++, opengl, direct3d, vertex-shader

I would like to be able to set a constant value for one of the vertex attributes in D3D11.

What would be the equivalent of the following code in D3D11?

```
glVertexAttribPointer(pos, &pos[0], ...);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(pos);

glVertexAttribPointer(color, NULL, ...);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(color);

glVertexAttrib4fv(color, &defaultColor);

glDrawArrays(...);
```

Comment: Why do you want to provide a per vertex attribute that is constant for every vertex?

Comment: so that I can use a shader with a data set that does not fully satisfy the shader's input signature

Answer (score 2):

When creating the input layout for the Input Assembler you can specify if an attribute is provided per vertex or per instance:

```
typedef enum D3D11_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION { 
  D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA    = 0,
  D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA  = 1
} D3D11_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION;
```

You can provide the color that is constant for all vertices on a per instance basis.

Comment: This is a good idea, wonder how it'd pan out from a multi-targeted engine perspective, for compatibilty with glVertexAttrib...

Answer (score 0):

Using glVertexAttrib4fv with glDrawArrays means the constant is the same to all vertices in the draw.

Tutorial 7 “Texture Mapping and Constant Buffers” in [directx sdk (June 2010)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6812) describes a general method of passing constants to a shader.